# Continuous function $f$ so that $\| g- f\|_1 = \int |g-f| \,\mathrm d \lambda < \epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The question:

> If $g$ belongs  $L(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ e $\epsilon >0, $ Then  exists a  continuous funtion  $f$ such that
> \begin{align*}
>     \| g- f\|_1 = \int |g-f|\,\mathrm d \lambda < \epsilon,
> \end{align*}

where $ \mathcal{B}$  is the Borel algebra and $ \lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I try the following :

> If  $g$ is positive, then exists a increasing  sequence of simple functions that converges to  $g,$ suppose  $(\varphi_n)_n $ such that  $\varphi_n = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \chi_{E_i}.$
> For the second part of the question  9J, we have that for every  $\chi_{E_i}$  we get a function  $f_{E_i}$ tal que $| \chi_{E_i} - f_{E_i} |< \frac{\epsilon}{2n}.$Thus, $f = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i f_{E_i}$ satisfies
> \begin{align*}
>     | \varphi_n - f| = | \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \chi_{E_i} - \sum_{i=1}^k a_i f_{E_i}| = |\sum_{i=1}^k a_i ( \chi_{E_i}- f_{E_i})|\leq \sum_{i=1}^k a_i  | \chi_{E_i}- f_{E_i}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, as $ \lim \varphi_n = g,$ and $\varphi_n$ is increasing,  by the monotone convergence theorem,
> \begin{align*}
>     \int g d \lambda = \lim \int \varphi_n d \lambda
> \end{align*}

I can't do more. Can someone help me, please?
The 9J question is here:

> If  $\epsilon > 0$ exists a continuous function  $f$ such that
> \begin{align*}
>     \|g- f\|_1 = \int |g-f| d \lambda < \epsilon
> \end{align*}

Comment: What is "the 9J question"?

Comment: The question that I speaked in the solution

Comment: Yes but I mean why do you call it 9J

Comment: Because it's the 9J question in the book (Bartle)